# HtmlGenericControl.Attribute.Add("class","someClass") not working when page is routed.

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

There is a **Default.aspx** page which contains a ***< i >*** Tag with class "fa fa-lock". The page loads fine with the glyphicon when accessed individually. But it does not change the class and hence the glyphicon of ***< i >*** when this page is accessed from some other page. For example, when **SomePage.aspx** routes to **Default.aspx** by this code *Server.Transfer("Default.aspx")*, it does not change the class of ***< i >*** which it should as per the following code.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
<a id="loginText" href="Login.aspx" runat="server">
  <i id="loginIcon" class="fa fa-lock" runat="server"></i>                       
Login
</a>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Session["FirstName"] != null)
        {
            loginText.InnerText = "Logout";
            loginIcon.Attributes.Add("class", "fa fa-unlock");
        }
        else
        {
            loginIcon.Attributes.Add("class", "fa fa-lock");            
        }
}
```